# What is a good delimiter for multiple Regex expressions in one string?

Tags: regex, string, configuration, split

I have a configuration where I need to store multiple Regex expressions in one string so I can split the string into an array of expressions that I can process individually.  What would be a good delimiter I can use for the split that won't be too complex and at the same time not get confused with parts of the actual regex expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could take
the comments tag (?#COMMENTTEXT) with an magic word to break
or
you can insert a magic word something like BREAKHEREVOODOO
or
something that is unlikey to occur like two underscores (__)

edit:
or you could put the regexes in a xml string that contains a list of CDATA-elements :-)

Answer (score 2):

A common delimiter is / but it can be changed if you want to use it in the regex.

If you really have to use a delimiter (I think, for example a JSON array would be a better alternative) you could introduce an escaping scheme: If it stand alone it is a delimiter, if it's preceded by a certain character (for example ) it is part of the regex.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something that's unlikely to occur in a real regex, for example a string that can never match, and thus will most likely never be used:

```
$!^
```

for example looks safe.

Answer (score 0):

If I absolutely had to do this, I would either use [hacktick's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167121/what-is-a-good-delimiter-for-multiple-regex-expressions-in-one-string/4167159#4167159) idea of using Regex-comments, or I would prepend the regexes with a header of counts.

Say I had 3 regexes, I would begin the data with `5;10;20;;` which would tell the parser that after `;;` a 5 characters long regex would follow, after that one 10 characters long and so forth. The actual details are debatable but I hope you understand my idea.

The final string would be something like `5;10;20;;barns[a-zA-Z_]*?^Bonobo Monkey Hope$`

Technically they also pass as a regex, but your code would of course require the header no matter what.

It's not beautiful but it's the most robust idea I can come up with.